# Using OF and FOR interchangeably

Tags: grammar

It's always hard to explain the difference between for and of in situations like this: the side mirror for this bus costs more than my car VS the side mirror of this bus costs more than my car.

I'd normally go for 'for' just because that's the nuance I would be going for when I need to say such a phrase, but it's really hard to describe the difference - can someone explain if there is a certain rule to this, or at least explain the exact difference in nuance in words?

Comment: If you consider that "costs more than my car" should be either "costs more than ***the one of*** my car", or, "costs more than ***the one for*** my car", then the choice has to be **for**. Note too, you are not buying the mirror ***of*** the bus – it is not for sale. You are buying one ***for*** the bus – a mirror from the parts shop.

Comment: So would you say that 'mirror of this bus' could be used for a 'general' statement- if you're looking at the bus and you just tell a friend a factual info, for ex, whereas 'mirror for this bus' is less general??

Comment: No, it depends on context. Your question is about the cost of a replacement mirror. You could say "The mirror of this bus is larger than the mirror of my car." But in neither case is the bus mirror larger than, or more expensive, than your car.

Comment: I'll say "kind of" rather than "no".  The "for" suggests purpose.  It allows you to imagine a side mirror on a store shelf, not yet attached to anything.  The "of" suggests direct association, such as attachment.   it allows you to imagine a side mirror designed for some other vehicle, but which happens to be in use right now on this bus.  Perhaps the side mirror of this bus costs more than my entire car because it's intended to withstand armor-piercing shells.

Comment: Note: It should be "**a** side mirror for this bus" (because you haven't picked out a particular one yet, and any of the ones at the parts shop would cost the same), or "**the** side mirror of this bus" (because the one that is already on the bus is a particular one).